# Svg is cut by a div

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a problem with my html/css code.
To explain, I have a div, in a button, on a Svg. But the div cuts the Svg.

Here a pic of the Svg without the div on :

[image]

And here a pic of the problem :

[image]

And here a part of my code :

```css
.head{
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 133);
    color: black;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top : 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menu{
     background-color: rgb(255, 196, 133);
     height: 80px;
     width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#menu:hover{
     background-color: rgb(255, 176, 91);

 }

 .bouton{
     height: 80px;
     width: 154px;
     border:none;
     background-color: rgb(255, 196, 133);
     transition: all 1s ease-out;

 }

 .bouton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 91);

 }

#menu:hover >.bouton{
     background-color: rgb(255, 176, 91);

 }

#bouton_menu:hover{
    fill:  rgb(255, 176, 91);
}

.bandeau:hover >.bouton{
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 91);
}

.bandeau:hover >#menu{
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 91);
}

.bandeau:hover #bouton_menu #bouton_menu_path,
.bandeau:hover{

  fill: rgb(255, 176, 91);
  
}

#bouton_menu #bouton_menu_path{
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test10.css">
    <title>Villa les Citronniers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    <div class="head">
    


    </div>

    <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%;margin-top : 0px;padding: 0px;overflow: hidden; display: flex;" class="bandeau" >

      <button class="bouton" id="button" style=" float: left; width: 154px; line-height: 80px;">
<div style="height: 10px; width: 50px; background-color: black; color: red; margin-top: 50px;">aaaaa</div>
          <svg fill="rgb(255, 196, 133)"  style="width: 154px; height: 80px; margin-left: -4px; margin-top: -2px;" id="bouton_menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 154 80">
    
    <path id="bouton_menu_path" d=" M0,0C44,0,96,.49,100,0c0,0,0,33.77,0,35,0,6,0,24,0,45H0Z">
      
      <animate id="animation1" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="300ms" to="M0,.17c44,0,155.26-.38,154,0-2.38.72-23.25,15.76-34,35-12.09,21.63-11.23,38.23-20,45H0Z"/>
      
     
      
      <animate id="animation2" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="300ms" to=" M0,0C44,0,96,.49,100,0c0,0,0,33.77,0,35,0,6,0,24,0,45H0Z"/>
      
    
    </path>

  </svg>

      </button>
         <div id="menu" style="display:inline-table; table-layout: fixed; width : 100%;">
            <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><a>Lien1</a></div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><a>Lien2</a></div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><a>Lien3</a></div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><a style="">Lien4</a></div>
       </div>


</div>








</header>
</body>

<footer>
    
</footer>









  
    


  

 
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var 
    element = document.getElementById("menu"),
    bouton = document.getElementById("button"),
    animation1 = document.getElementById("animation1"),
    
    animation2 = document.getElementById("animation2");
    

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  if (button.classList.contains("1")) {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = true; 
    button.classList.remove("1");
    animation2.beginElement();
    element.style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("button").style.width="100px";
    document.getElementById("button").style.transition="all 0s ease-out"; 
    document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundColor="rgb(255, 196, 133)";
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("button").disabled = false; 
    }, 1000); 


  } else {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = true; 
    button.classList.add("1");  
    document.getElementById("button").style.width="100px";
    element.style.width = "0px";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("button").style.width="154px";
    animation1.beginElement(); 
    document.getElementById("button").style.transition="all 0s ease-out"; 
    document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"; 
    
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = false; }, 1000);
  

    

  }
  
}, false);
</script>
```

So i have a little bit of JavaScript for my menu. I don't know if it's that the problem. I just want set an icon for my button.
Thanks you ^^

Comment: Note that it is invalid HTML to place a `<div>` element inside a `<button>` element. Buttons can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content).

Comment: Your HTML doesn't show the problem. Can you update the snippet so that it does?

Comment: I can see the problem inside your code. You must provide more info.-

Comment: Added more code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you to remove from the div with class 'bandeau' the rule 'overflow: hidden'. This truncates everything outside the div.

Comment: please show a picture of the result you want to have